# Bootstrap ASP.Net button group retain value on postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap button group with three radio buttons. I also have a hidden field so I can get the selected value in my code behind. The code for the buttons is:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="parentofit">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidValue" runat="server" Value="Beginning" />
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="label1" runat="server">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" runat="server">
        Radio 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="label2" runat="server">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" runat="server">
        Radio 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="label3" runat="server">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" runat="server">
        Radio 3
    </label>
</div>
```

I also have Javascript to set the hidden field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var parent = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $(parent).find('input').val($(this).text());
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
```

When I submit the page, the hidden field has the correct value. When the page get's reloaded the button group is reset back to the first field.

How do I retain the value on postback? How do I set the value initially programatically?

TIA

Jeff

Comment: How about using RadioButton server controls instead of html controls?

Comment: I've tried that. Still has the same thing. I can set the radio button as checked in page_prerender but it looks just like the other buttons.
Also - if you look at the input they are already been running at the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the Form Post data and set the radiobutton value manually in page load.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack && Request.Form["options"] != null)
{
    HtmlInputRadioButton hirb = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
    hirb.Value = Request.Form["options"];
}
```

A more complex solution would be to create your own Control Adapter for overwriting the design of the radiobuttons.

Comment: Thank you. But the buttons won't be set. I can save the value but the display buttons get reset.

Comment: Are you setting the values somewhere in code? If so make sure you do so inside `if (Page.IsPostBack == false) { //set data here }`

Comment: I've tried both setting the radio buttons and setting the hidden field. It appears as if every time there is a postback the buttons get reset.